Cookies are not creating after login
I am working rigth now on e-commerce project using ReactJS, NodeJS, Express, Apache, VPS(ubuntu). The problem is that after sign-in coockies are not creating. So my loging code is working well, only coockies are not creating. Backend of coockies, backend of login. On localhost everything working fine. But on my VPS server not. ReactJS login code.
PS.
My web-site is using https protocol.
I am asked Chat GPT about this problem. He recomended me this. But its doesn't helped.
app.set('trust proxy', 1);  cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none' }

Please [edit] your question to include a minimal reproducible example so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Added RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" which should point to HTTPS.
This header informs the application that the request was made over a secure protocol.
Added app.set('trust proxy', 1); This will allow Express to properly handle the X-Forwarded-Proto header and use secure cookies if the request was made over HTTPS.
Added sameSite: 'None' Modern browsers enforce the SameSite attribute for cookies, which can prevent cookies from being sent in some cross-origin requests. Consider setting the SameSite attribute to 'None' along with the secure flag to allow the cookies to be sent across domains.

PS.


nano ~/.bashrc ;


add this line of code export NODE_ENV=production ;


save the file ;


source ~/.bashrc ;


sudo nano /etc/environment ;


add this line NODE_ENV=production ;


echo $NODE_ENV ;
If everything is set up correctly, you should see production in the output.



sameSite : 'none' did not work for me. Is your sing-up a cross access request or same-site.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
